# Gnuplot - graphing a matrix and replacing the squares with figures

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to graph a 80x80 matrix from a dataset with the following code:

```
set terminal png
set output "Matrix.png"
set title "Matrix"
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
set palette define (0 "black", 1 "red", 2 "blue", 3 "yellow", 4 "gold", 5 "green")
set cbrange [0:5]
plot "Lattice.txt" matrix with image
```

Now I need to do two modifications, the first one is to have it on a grayscale which I figure I can do by replacing the palette with `set palette gray`

The second want is to replace each square with figures, or show the figures inside the squares. figures likes triangles, crosses, circles.

Is there a way to define each number with each symbol, like I did previously with the palette colours?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do the same with variable pointtypes. Check `help points`. Type `test` in the gnuplot console and you will see the available pointtypes. The example below is still with color palette because it looks nicer.

**Code:**

```
### variable pointtype
reset session
set size square

# create some random test data
set print $Data
    do for [y=1:15] {
        Line = ''
        do for [x=1:15] {
            Line = Line.sprintf(" %d", int(rand(0)*6))
        }
        print Line
    }
set print

set palette define (0 "black", 1 "red", 2 "blue", 3 "yellow", 4 "gold", 5 "green")

myPointtypes     = "2 5 7 9 11 13"
myPointtype(col) = int(word(myPointtypes,int(column(col))+1))

set offsets 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5

plot $Data u 1:2:(myPointtype(3)):3 matrix w p pt var lc palette notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]